# Start displaying tkinter treeview from an item

Tags: tkinter, treeview, display, selecteditem

I have a tkinter treeview with a vertical scrollbar that loads around 1,000 items sorted. On the 400th item inserted, I have a set focus and selection_set function on that item's iid.  All is good so far.  But the tree starts displaying from the first item. How can I start displaying the tree so that the 400th item with the focus is displayed on the screen. In essence, start displaying the tree from the middle on start up. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `Treeview.see(iid)` where `iid` is the item ID of the focused item.

Comment: Thank you so much acw1668. It worked like a charm.